# Is there a way to password protect all vhosts on an apache server without adding code to each vhost?

Tags: apache

We have a development server and would like a generic password that applies to all virtual hosts that would help to prevent Google from indexing the sites on that server and force users to enter a password to access any sites. The indexing is the most important aspect of the problem and we don't want to risk having robots.txt files accidentally being pushed to our production servers. I assume you could edit httpd.conf to do this but don't see how that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to lock the whole root (/var/www ?) whit the '<'Directory'>' instruction in the main httpd.conf ?